# Pandas - Modify by string values in each cell by using search

Tags: string, pandas

I have pandas dataframe include a column a with content like this `'<152/abcx>' ,'<42/da>', '<2/kiw>'`. What I want to do is based on the content , remove "<",">", and create two new separate column like this column b : `152 ; 42; 2`, column c: `'abcx', 'da', 'kiw'`.

```
df.a.str[df.a.str.find('<')+1:df.a.str.find('/')-1]
```

the code I tried doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['<152/abcx>' ,'<42/da>', '<2/kiw>']})
df = df['a'].str.strip('<>').str.split('/', expand=True)
df.columns = ['columnb', 'columnc']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  columnb columnc
0     152    abcx
1      42      da
2       2     kiw
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I guess you are finding:

```
import pandas as pd 
def f(x):
    x = x.split('/')
    return pd.Series([x[0].replace('<',''),x[1].replace('>','')])


df =pd.DataFrame({'a':['<152/abcx>' ,'<42/da>', '<2/kiw>']})
df[['c1','c2']] = df['a'].apply(f)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            a   c1    c2
0  <152/abcx>  152  abcx
1     <42/da>   42    da
2     <2/kiw>    2   kiw
[Finished in 2.7s]
```